# About asymptotic in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I solved a lot of convergence problems, but now I realized I wasn't thinking  too much applying tests and rules.

**Question**

Suppose we have a series:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}+(-1)^n}
$$
It looks like for big $n$
$$
\frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}+(-1)^n} \approx \frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}}
$$
And then I think we can reasonably conclude that both the series of LHS and of RHS converges or diverges simultaneously.

But how we can show that more rigorously? I mean, what Test or Rule should I apply? For example, we can't use Limit Comparison Test now, since both sequences may be negative.

Comment: I don't think you can apply any simple tests for the above series. The "negative" terms definitely do complicate the situation a lot - the alternation between positive and negative terms will, for the most part, not have any "nice" pattern to it. Unless I am missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a Taylor development (at $\infty$) and see how that goes. Namely, write
$$
\frac{1}{n^{2/3}+(-1)^n}
= \frac{1}{n^{2/3}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{4/3}} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right) \tag{1}
$$
using that $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$. This means that
$$
\frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}+(-1)^n}
= \underbrace{\frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}}}_{a_n} - \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^n\cos n}{n^{4/3}} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right)}_{b_n} \tag{2}
$$
the $o()$ since $|\cos n|\leq 1$. You can then write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos n}{n^{2/3}+(-1)^n} 
= \sum_{n=1}^N a_n +\sum_{n=1}^N b_n \tag{3}
$$

Note that $ \sum_{n=1}^N b_n$ is *absolutely* convergent now, so the series on the RHS converges if, and only if, $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ converges.

---

*In general, you can/should do the Taylor series development to as many terms you need to obtain as the last part an absolutely convergent series. It (very) often works.*

Comment: Very nice! ${+1}$

Comment: An example of series where this doesn't allow you to conclude: $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\log n + (-1)^n}$ (as you won't eventually get an absolutely converging series when doing a Taylor expansion to finitely many terms).

Comment: @ClementC. I think you've used the fact here that if $\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ converges then $o(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}})$. Is it obvious?

Comment: @LevonMinasian For the convergence of $b_n$, you can now apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to the (absolute value) of the series, since they are absolutely convergent. That is, if $\sum_{n} x_n$ is absolutely convergent, then so is $\sum_{n} (x_n+o(x_n))$ since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n|}{|x_n+o(x_n)|}=1$$